# How do I recreate the layout of the swing gui made with netbeans autogenerated code?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I already made this in Netbeans GUI Builder:

[image]

But its full of auto generated code and I don't know where to place my extra codes, so I want to change it to manual code. I tried `BorderLayout` and I also started learning `GridBagLayout` but I still can't replicate it. I'm stuck here for a week and I need to pass my java system this month.

- <s>Can you code this for me please?</s>
- What layouts should I use to manually replicate the GUI?
- How can I easily change the size of a `textarea` (pixels) without using [`setColumns`] or [`setRows`]?

Comment: could you explain more what do you mean by changing the size of textarea ? do you mean to define its size in creation?

Comment: There are tutorials that explain how to integrate your code with the autogenerated code from Netbeans. Have you looked at those? There is a lot of flexibility.

Comment: (1-) Cross posted: https://coderanch.com/t/727698/java/create-GUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I can help you is that you can use `BorderLayout` as layout for your Frame.

The black screen with a `Panel` will be in a `BoxLayout` ([more informations](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/java-swing-boxlayout-example/)) in center of `BorderLayout`. The `Panel` will contain the elements below the black screen, you can use `GirLayout` (except the two buttons below the `textarea`)

The text area and the two Buttons on east in a `BoxLayout` and placed in the east of the main `BorderLayout`

[image]

(sorry for the bad drawing, but I hope it helps you to understand more the structure of layouts)

take a look [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/swing/java-swing-layout-example/) to learn more about Layouts.

for the textarea, is that you are looking for?

```
new JTextArea(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
```

create the textarea withou using `setColumns` or `setRows`

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I easily change the size of a textarea (pixels) without using [setColumns] or [setRows]?

You should not attempt to do that.

The row/columns methods are designed to give the text area a hint so it can calculate its own preferred size.

The rows/columns are there to make it easy for you.

> I also started learning GridBagLayout

That is probably a good place to start. For example I see a 2 x 2 grid:

1. the black area - this would grow vertically and horizontally
2. the text area - this would grow vertically
3. buttons under the black area - fixed size
4. buttons under the text area - grow horizontally

Then for areas 3 and 4 you would use a panel to hold the components. These panels can use other layout managers.

Area 3 might be a `BoxLayout`. It might also contain a panel using a `GridLayout` for the two combo boxes.

Area 4 would probably be a `GridLayout`.

The main point about layout management is that you can nest panels with different layout managers.

Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples

Answer (score -1):

You can set layout of your panel to `null`.

Then you have the opportunity to place and size every element via `.setBounds()`,

It's much work, but this way you can design your gui as you want.

example:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);
JButton button = new JButton("hit me");
button.setBounds(10, 10, 50, 20); //(xpos,ypos,width,height)
```

Comment: (1-) Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. Use layout manager makes the code easier to maintain and it is more flexible. It allows components to grow/shrink when the frame is resized.

Comment: @camickr that is true of course, but the way I explained still allows designing your gui as you want in a hardcoded way